# Show IF formula instead of result

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm having some trouble with getting the right result when Excel executes certain VBA code for my macro.

Instead of placing the formula in the desired cell it gives me the result of that formula, in this case TRUE or FALSE.

This code works fine, it puts the formula in the cell and the result is shown:

```
Range("AL12").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUM" & ActiveCell.Formula
```

This code don't work, I get an error:

```
Range("AL12").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF" & ActiveCell.Formula
```

And this code works but it doesn't give the formula, only the result:

```
Range("AL12").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "" = "IF" & ActiveCell.Formula
```

or

```
Range("AL12").Select
ActiveCell.Value= "" = "IF" & ActiveCell.Value
```

How can I get the macro to put the formula in the cell so the formula can calculate it's result which should be 0 or 1 and not TRUE or FALSE. Exactly like it does in the first line of code?

Comment: It isn't very well possible to construct a formula from unknown parts. For your first example, it seems that your ActiveCell contains something like `(A3:A12)`. Therefore your first example works. But your second example must have quite a different value in the ActiveCell because you probably wouldn't expect `=IF(A3:12)' to give any result. Therefore, please disclose the format of `ActiveCell.Formula` for each of your examples.

Comment: 'ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=CONCATENATE(""=ALS('D:\Google Drive\Pat Bud\Begrotingen\[Begroting "",RC3,""."",RC2,""-"",RC7,"".xlsx]Totaal'!$L$66=0"","";"",1,"";"",0, "")"")"'

Comment: All cells have `general' format`. What i'm doing is reducing this concatenate: `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=CONCATENATE(""=IF('D:\Google Drive\Pat Bud\Begrotingen\[Begroting "",RC3,""."",RC2,""-"",RC7,"".xlsx]Totaal'!$L$66=0"","";"",1,"";"",0, "")"")"` to the next formula by using `Copy.Value` wich results in (example):`=IF('D:\Google Drive\Pat Bud\Begrotingen\[Begroting 207.17-1.xlsx]Totaal'!$L$66=0;1;0)` wich is exactly what i want but it needs a manual `ENTER` to start working.

Comment: The code that works does exactly the same but puts `=SUM` instead of `=IF` to the same generated formula (without the Excel `IF` statements in it of course). Just like you said.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> ActiveCell.Formula = "" = "IF" & ActiveCell.Formula
>
> ActiveCell.Formula = "" = "IF" & ActiveCell.Value
> ```

No. These are not *"working but putting the result instead of the formula"*. They are just writing `FALSE` to the cell. Because for example the first statement means this:

> ```
> ActiveCell.Formula = (  "" = ("IF" & ActiveCell.Formula)  )
> ```

where the RHS is a comparison that obviously results in `False`.

As for the other forms in your OP, i.e.

> ```
> ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUM" & ActiveCell.Formula
> ```

You are just prepending `"=SUM"` to an existing formula, or to nothing in case old cell was empty; in any case the resulting formula has wrong syntax.

Comment: I see and yes I am just prepending "=SUM" to an existing formula. The reason I do so is because the source formula was a concatenate and when I only copy the value of this concatenate formula to another cell it gives me the right result (another formula) but i need to manually enter the cell and hit "ENTER" for the formula to work. By prepending "=SUM" I managed to get it working but I can't do this with "IF". Thanks for your input.

Comment: *"By prepending "=SUM" I managed to get it working"* Doh, you must be using something else, not Excel. Might be a tag error.

Comment: It's definitely Excel, any way, thanks. I'll find a way to get it working one day.

Answer (score 0):

If the activecell already has a formula in it and you wish to modify or enhance that formula with *VBA*, you must pay attention to the leading ***=***

Say we have a cell that contains:

```
=SUM(A1:A123)
```

and we run:

```
Sub Vig()
    Dim s As String
    s = ActiveCell.Formula
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

We get:

[image]

If we want to embed this in an **IF** statement, we could use something like:

```
Sub Vig_2()
    Dim s As String
    s = Mid(ActiveCell.Formula, 2)
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(" & s & "=0,9999," & s & ")"
End Sub
```

[image]

The ***MID()*** removes that original ***=***

Comment: Thanks Gary, I tried a couple of variations based on your code but I still only get the result without the formula. I'll keep fiddling, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

This is never going to work smoothly. It has too much instability built into the system you designed. The proper way is to get each datum and write it somewhere, and not to start doing any calculations until you have all your data safely written down.

You can write to workbook cells. These can be in the same sheet where you want the result, in visible or hidden columns, or on another sheet which is either visible or hidden or very hidden (meaning the user can't make it visible without help from VBA). You can also "write" into memory, meaning assign the values to variables.

The same method should also be applied to the parameters. For example, a web address shouldn't be in a formula. It should either be in a cell or in a constant declared in the code. In fact, one of the first rules you should learn to observe is not to write any constants into any formula, ever. Formulas manipulate data. They don't contain them.

While you are revamping your structure I also suggest that you examine the relationship between VBA and worksheet functions. Cases where VBA should be used to write functions are rather rare. Usually, VBA is used not as a supplement to function but as their replacement. Worksheet function aren't mean to do very complicated jobs like you are trying to make them do. The resulting code is convoluted and ends up being beyond trouble shooting (as it your current experience). Put all of that into VBA, and what took you weeks and weeks to arrive at a compromise will take you just a few hours to achieve perfection.

Comment: Thanks Variatus, that's a very clear insight on how to construct a proper macro. Looks like I have a lot to do to revamp the structure but I feel motivated :)